# How to increase the delivery speed of WSO2 Message Broker?

Tags: performance, wso2, mqtt, wso2-message-broker

I want to create a publish and subscribe model for developing a IoT project. I have created it using Python language. Everything is working well and fine, but there seems to be a delay of 3 seconds to reach the message to the subscriber from the publisher.

Is there any way to minimize the delay in message delivery and increase its performance in **WSO2 Message Broker** or any suggestion...

Comment: There is nowhere enough information in this question for anybody to be able to answer it. Please read the [doc](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking good questions. You need to show your code and explain the system you have deployed in a lot more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Performance tuning guide for MB [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Performance+Tuning+Guide). Also, check the message publisher and consumer performance guide as well [2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Message+Publisher+and+Consumer+Performance).

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Performance+Tuning+Guide
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Message+Publisher+and+Consumer+Performance

Comment: Please include the solution/answer in your post. Just linking to other pages can result in useless answers caused by Linkrot. Also, the linked pages might help solving the problem, but they are not an anwser to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `broker.xml`,

```
<messageAccumulationTimeout>2000</messageAccumulationTimeout>
```

this parameter to 1000, default 3000